# How to Integrate Factors Found by Inspection?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example if I have this problem:

$$y^2 (1-x^2)dx + x(x^{2} y + 2x + y)dy = 0$$

And the answer is : $x^2 +2xy + y^2 + 4x + 1$

How do I solve that? Having a hard time solving it. Please help, thanks!

Comment: What techniques have you learned to solve these kinds of problem?

Comment: I doubt the answer is correct.

Comment: Of course the answer is not correct. The answer should be an equation, not an expression